# Surgery During the "The Three Weeks" and Tisha b'Av

Tags: medicine, tisha-bav, three-weeks

Are there restrictions having surgery during the "Three Weeks" and Tisha b'Av? What are the sources for restrictions/limitations if there any?

Comment: I believe R Herschel Schachter (in a YUTorah recording) holds that there is no need to postpone, but I don't recall which shiur/whether this is accurate

Comment: This is only relevant of you believe in astrology. If not, then astrologically rooted practices are not relevant (and may themselves even be prohibited).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All surgery that can safely be postponed until after Tisha B'Av should be postponed.  See R. Simcha Bunim Cohen's Halachos for Daily Living, volume on the Three Weeks and Fast Days.  Published by ArtScroll.

Comment: There's a general ruling mentioned in, I believe, Shulchan Aruch stating that a person should avoid "dangerous situations" where possible. However, I think this was mentioned only regarding the 9 days and not the entire 3 week period. Obviously, if postponing the surgery would make you more ill, then don't wait at all.

Answer (score 0):

In Kovetz Halchos(Rav Shmuel Kaminetsky) perek 7:4 : it is better to wait and push off surgery if possible since there is a chance of danger. This is also what Rav Yaakov Kaminetsky paskened in his Emes L'Yaakov siman 551 (haarah 515).

However, Rav Moshe Feinstein paskened one does not need to be particular about this (שמעתתא דמשה,שמועות סימן תקנא סקמ"ב )

This is referring to the 9 days.